# Resizing android tabs

Tags: android, resize, android-tablayout

I followed [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) in order to use tablayout and make tabs in my app. I managed to do that but they aren't sized equally on the full width of my screen, here is what I get:

[image]

So I was wondering if there's a way to resize each tab either programmatically or through the xml files.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to have it spaced equally change the tabs from `app:tabMode="scrollable"` to `app:tabMode="fixed"`

Comment: That's the solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can set mode for TabLayout by ***setTabMode()*** method. 
Set the behavior mode for the Tabs in this layout. The valid input options are:

- MODE_FIXED: Fixed tabs display all tabs concurrently and are best used with content that benefits from quick pivots between tabs.
- MODE_SCROLLABLE: Scrollable tabs display a subset of tabs at any given moment, and can contain longer tab labels and a larger number of tabs. They are best used for browsing contexts in touch interfaces when users don’t need to directly compare the tab labels. This mode is commonly used with a ViewPager.

If you want to size equally on the full screen's width, do follow:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```